# Which of Colgate's messages about when to brush should one follow?

Tags: dentistry, toothpaste

Tubes of Colgate® toothpaste say:

> Brush teeth thoroughly, preferably after each meal, or as directed by a health care practioner

The colgate.com page [Over Brushing Teeth: Too Much Of A Good Thing | Colgate®](https://www.colgate.com/en-us/oral-health/brushing-and-flossing/over-brushing-teeth-too-much-of-a-good-thing#:%7E:text=Wait%20at%20least%2060%20minutes) says:

> If you are conscientious about your oral hygiene, then you probably brush your teeth at least twice a day.
> …
> Don't brush right after eating. Wait at least 60 minutes after eating or drinking to brush your teeth, …

For proper dental hygiene, is it better to brush after every meal, as the product says, or to *not* brush after eating, as the article says?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a Medical Sciences answer to this sort of question.